# SignalR hub returning Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302 Net Core Angular and Azure

Tags: angular, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, signalr-hub

I have an angular application that connects to Net Core through SignalR to get info. Locally works perfectly but when the application is doing the request from Azure is throwing this error

WebSocket connection to 'wss://mysite.azurewebsites.net/notifications?id=someId&access_token=sometoken' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302
Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': undefined

But is still returning the data and doing the connection and bringing the info, just annoying errors on console

this is my Angular Side call to signalR

```
  private createConnection() {
this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                            .withUrl(`${this.libraryConfig.api.notification.baseUrl}/notifications`, { accessTokenFactory: () => this.access_token })
                            .build(); 
  }
```

and this is my code on StartUp on Net Core

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://sts.windows.net/tenat/v2.0";
                options.Audience = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").GetSection("Audience").Value;
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;
              options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                        // If the request is for our hub...
                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                                (path.StartsWithSegments("/notifications")))
                        {
                            // Read the token out of the query string
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };

            });
```

Ive been trying every solution I could find but nothing works.

NOTE: Im using Azure Active Directory to sign in the client

Comment: Your hub url is probably not (entirely) correct. Maybe a missing slash at the end?

Comment: It works locally perfectly and it’s returning everything on Azure not sure what could be causing this errors cause url is the same for the hub at the end

Comment: Enable logging and turn on log streaming in Azure. SignalR uses multiple transport protocols so it's probably failing with socket and using long polling instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Websocket in azure app service. It's under Configuration ->General Setings

Comment: It is enabled for the app service that contains Angular and for the app service that contains the API and still nothing

Comment: Your site is hosted on http://www.example.com
Your SignalR app is hosted on http://signalr.example.com
CORS should be configured in the SignalR app to only allow the origin www.example.com. How about cors settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Also please check to make sure createConnection() on angular side happens after authentication is completed. I think it is more like the case as you received 302 redirection

Comment: Connection is happening after authentication. I don’t have a resource on Azure for the SignalR, is using the one created by the net core api app. Should I use one?

Comment: No that is fine. You don't need to use Signal R service. Can you capture the network traffic (devtool in chrome) to see what the detail about this 302 redirect? also mysite.azurewebsites.net/notifications is your hub, what is your angular app url looks like?

Comment: it wont let me post pics cause im new to the community

Comment: authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri..... thats the line with CORS errors on Network

Comment: Cors setting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: CORS settings are fine not sure why keeps complaining about it, its so annoying being on this for 3 days :(

Comment: Without the logs I cannot help much. New to stack overflow :-)